# Constructor dependency injection: unique_ptr + move vs shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Let's assume we have something like this:

```
struct Complex{
    Complex(Part1 p1, Part2 p2, Part3 p3)
}

Part1 p1; 
Part2 p2;
Part3 p3;
```

However passing copies is not effective, so we need to move to pointers. The questions is what type to use — `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`

At first glance, since `Complex` is a real owner of `p1, p2, p3`, it seems `unique_ptr` is better; however, since it could not be copied, we would need to use `std::move`.

So my question is — what is the better way for this case, create `unique_ptr` out of `Part`, and then use `move` in `Complex`'s constructor, or create `shared_ptr` from the beginning and use `shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: *However passing copies not effective, so we need to move to pointers.* or you make Complex and Part movable?

Comment: Complex - is just a complex, long living object. But for the current moment I not plan to implement "rule of five".

Comment: Also not if it's a solution to your problem? Anyway: smart pointers represent some kind of ownership, so the answer seems easy: if p1/p2/p3 are not *shared*, don't use *shared*_ptr?

Comment: I agree, but maybe creating and moving unique_ptr less efffective or have some side effects, than just creating shared_ptr?

Comment: @silent_coder Copying a `shared_ptr` involves an **atomic** increment, destroying a `shared_ptr` involves an **atomic** decrement. Moving a `unique_ptr` involves two pointer assignments, destroying an empty `unique_ptr` is a no-op. Which do you think is faster? ;-)

Comment: if `Part1/2/3` are pure value types,  why not just pass it by reference ? It is not particularly clear from your question about the data type of `Part1/2/3`

Comment: @Angew Didn't know such details. Thanks, now this is clear for me.

Comment: In my edit, I replaced one use of `Complex` with `Part` where I think it makes more sense and was what you intended. Please check whether that's the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best solution would be to make the `Part` types cheap to move, and move them in. However, if that is not an option, you will have to resort to managing them dynamically.

As you say, `Complex` owns the parts, so it should accept them as `std::uniqe_ptr<Part>` and move these pointers into itself. Moving a `std::unique_ptr` is dirt cheap: it probably involes just two pointer assignments.

On the other hand, using `std::shared_ptr` and copying that involves an unnecessary **atomic** increment (for creating the copy) and decrement (for destroying the original). Atomic operations are certainly far from cheap for today's cache-heavy, multi-core processors.

So just stick to the intended semantics of your code (unique ownership, which is idiomatically expressed by `std::unique_ptr`), and you will get good performance as a bonus.

Comment: @GeorgeAl One to point the destination to the pointee, and one to point the source to null. Otherwise, the destructor of source wouldn't know it's empty, and would deallocate the pointee.